# Get enumeration underlying type through CodeModel

Tags: c#-code-model

Using the CodeModel, I have a CodeEnum object representing an enumeration. How can I know what is the underlying type of this enumeration?
Is there an equivalent to Enum.GetUnderlyingType in this API? Or is there another way to get it?